# Create pandas column from matching words in other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with several substance columns, like this:

```
import random

values = ['oil', 'gas', 'water']
modifier = ['dirty', 'crude', 'fuel']
wordzip = [modifier, values]

data = [[wordzip[0][random.randint(0,2)] + ' ' + wordzip[1][random.randint(0,2)] for c in wordzip[0]] for i in range(7)]

pd.DataFrame(data = data, columns = ['A', 'B', 'C'])

             A            B            C   
0    dirty gas    crude oil  dirty water 
1  dirty water     fuel gas    dirty gas  
2  dirty water     fuel gas    dirty oil  
3     fuel oil  crude water    crude gas  
4  dirty water     fuel oil  dirty water  
5    crude oil   fuel water    dirty oil
6   fuel water    crude gas  crude water
```

I want to create a new column with the values within on those columns that contains the word "oil". So the final df should look like this:

```
             A            B            C          D
0    dirty gas    crude oil  dirty water  crude oil
1  dirty water     fuel gas    dirty gas  NaN
2  dirty water     fuel gas    dirty oil  dirty oil
3     fuel oil  crude water    crude gas  fuel oil
4  dirty water     fuel oil  dirty water  fuel oil
5    crude oil   fuel water    dirty oil  crude oil
6   fuel water    crude gas  crude water  NaN
```

I tried `df[['A', 'B', 'C']].apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('oil'))` but that returns a Boolean dataframe, not the values themselves.

Comment: 5D could be crude oil or dirty oil?

Comment: Yes, my pseudocode sucks, sorry about that. Imagine there is just one "oil" value per row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's use `stack` + `extract`:

```
df['D'] = df.stack().str.extract(r'(.* oil)').groupby(level=0).first()[0]
df
             A            B            C          D
0    dirty gas    crude oil  dirty water  crude oil
1  dirty water     fuel gas    dirty gas        NaN
2  dirty water     fuel gas    dirty oil  dirty oil
3     fuel oil  crude water    crude gas   fuel oil
4  dirty water     fuel oil  dirty water   fuel oil
5    crude oil   fuel water    dirty oil  crude oil
6   fuel water    crude gas  crude water        NaN
```

Comment: Never mind. This works really well. I was looking at my index numbers, not the Series length. And I can just subset the columns I want to extract the values from.

Comment: Follow-up question: if each column had a numerical column beside it, how would you extract just the "oil" quantities into a single column?

Comment: @robroc you will need to select all the non numeric columns first and then repeat this process. You can look into select_dtypes.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

values = ['oil', 'gas', 'water']
modifier = ['dirty', 'crude', 'fuel']
wordzip = [modifier, values]
data = [[wordzip[0][random.randint(0,2)] + ' ' + wordzip[1][random.randint(0,2)] for c in wordzip[0]] for i in range(7)]
df=pd.DataFrame(data = data, columns = ['A', 'B', 'C'])

temp=df[df[['A', 'B', 'C']].apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('oil'))]
df['D'] = temp.A.combine_first(temp.B).combine_first(temp.C)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `applymap` with `bfill`

```
df[df.applymap(lambda x : 'oil' in x)].bfill(1).loc[:,'A']
Out[80]: 
0          NaN
1          NaN
2     fuel oil
3    crude oil
4    crude oil
5     fuel oil
6          NaN
Name: A, dtype: object
```

Comment: This was the exact same answer I was going to post 10 seconds ago until you already did. Nice.

Comment: Had to change my answer to something else ;)

Comment: @coldspeed  I like yours better:-)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with `str` accessor functions in case I need to use `str.contains` or `str.startswith`.

Answer (score 0):

This answer sums the strings horizontally and then uses regex extract to get the desired output:

```
# insert temporary columns containing spaces for this regex implementation to work
df.insert(1,'a',' ')
df.insert(3,'b',' ')

# this regex contains a capture group which will get 'oil' instances and the preceding word
df['D'] = df.sum(axis=1).str.extract('([a-z]+ oil)')

# remove the temporary columns
df.drop(['a', 'b'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```